# jQuery FancyBox Messing up Buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, button, fancybox

I have a couple of jQuery FancyBoxes on my web page. They're getting put onto the page through some ajax that also brings other stuff onto the page like buttons and such. But, for some reason, after I open a FancyBox window, I get these style errors on my page until I reload it:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'button'
```

This button works well though completely until I click and open a FancyBox. Here's my fancy box code and my button code.

```
jQuery('.fancybox-media').fancybox({
    fitToView: false,
    width: '100%',
    height: '100%',
    autoSize: false,
    closeClick: false,
    openEffect: 'none',
    closeEffect: 'none'
});
```

button:

```
$('.adminbutton').button();
```

**EDIT**

I've definitely narrowed it down to a jQuery UI and FancyBox conflict. After a FancyBox is opened, I can no longer get jQuery UI methods to function any more. Anyone know a workaround or a good solid fix for this?

**EDIT 2**

I kind of found a temporary workaround, but it just doesn't seem right. It does fix the problem though. After the close of the FancyBox I reinclude jQuery UI onto the page with some other jQuery.

```
$.getScript('/js/jquery-ui.js');
```

Comment: Order of JS files is the problem..

Comment: Possible duplicate..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7924222/uncaught-typeerror-object-object-object-has-no-method-fancybox

Comment: `button` isn't a method, so the fancybox hasn't been applied to that element.

Comment: Make a Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: @AramKocharyan : maybe the OP is using jQuery UI, check http://jqueryui.com/button/ and http://api.jqueryui.com/button/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a real way around the error since no one else offered any real help. The order of my JS files was *not* the problem, it was ajax. For some reason, jQuery light box plugins that use ajax seem to break a lot of code. But, by making these lightboxes into iframes instead, and of course adding my JS and CSS headers to the pages I was including, I got it to work without any problems.

---

Simple?

When using jQuery Light Box plugins, use iframes instead of ajax when your page relies on other jQuery such as jQuery UI.